# Convert from double (GNU scientific library) to SC16Q11 in C

Tags: c, complex-numbers, gsl, floating-point-conversion

I'm using the GNU Scientific Library to define & use complex numbers. A complex number is defined as

```
typedef struct{
    double dat[2];
    } gsl_complex;
```

Which is just representing real and imaginary parts as a double-precision floating point (each part using up 8 bytes). I need to pass an array of these values to a D/A converter which works with a SC16Q11 (signed-complex, 16-bit Q11) format.

From what I understand, a 16-bit processor that uses the Q11 format uses 16-(11+1)=4 bits for the integer portion, leaving one sign bit and 11 bits for the fractional portion.Is this correct? How can I convert between these two data types?

The documentation states that each IQ sample is an interleaved IQ pair, where each value of the pair is an int16_t.

Comment: `short real = dat[0] * 2048;` and `short imag = dat[1] * 2048;`

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation?

Comment: @Degustaf: http://nuand.com/~jon/doc/libbladeRF-v0.14.0/group___f_m_t___m_e_t_a.html#gga4c61587834fd4de51a8e2d34e14a73b2a92cfbda7a5577c809e2ff6123f8f30b6

Comment: You should check out the BladeRF GitHub https://github.com/jynik/OOKiedokie/blob/fc2e1ba15f47f4d2acbc991bb0305f79b41e1b2f/src/complexf.h **and** https://github.com/rajeevvats/dump1090/blob/a9d512474750e9890d9ec624187963009a35fb45/convert.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a Q11 format is a Q4.11 (or Q5.11 if you count the sign bit to the int bits).

more informations can you find at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_%28number_format%29

you can do the conversion with:

```
int16_t number[2];
number[0] = round(dat[0] * 2048);
number[1] = round(dat[1] * 2048);
```

the 2048 comes from 2^11. It's also written in the link.

Comment: Should not it be `round(dat[0] * 2048)`?  This would nicely round + and - numbers.

Comment: @chux yes, but sometimes the error in the least significant bit is not so important than the speed of the conversion

Comment: Agree about the need for good judgment on precise functionality versus speed.  Example: If code uses `sqrt()`, one would expect it to be correct to the last bit.  If code needed something faster, _then_ I would create `sqrt_fast()` which  may only provide approximate answers.  Functionality 1st then performance optimization.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I followed the approach on wikipedia before, but didn't get the correct values, which led me to post here. I printf two values, `real=round(2048*GSL_REAL(x[i]))` and `GSL_REAL(x[i])` - x[i] being one element of an N bit vector, with the elements being type gsl_complex. Before the conversion, printf shows -0.707110-j0.707104 (just repeat the above for the imaginary part), and after conversion -1448-j1448. Any ideas?

Comment: that is the correct value in Q11 format. `-1448` corresponds to `-0,70703125` in Q11 format.